# Gauss' Law- Hollow Sphere with Non-Uniform Charge Distribution

Tags: electromagnetism, electrostatics, charge, gauss-law

I am confused about the solving for the E field inside of a hollow sphere with a non uniform charge distribution. I understand conceptually that the unbalanced charge distribution would lead to an E-field inside of the sphere, but if I apply Gauss' law, there is no charge enclosed, so it comes out to be E = 0. *Does Gauss' law not apply in this situation, or am I using it wrong?* And if it does not apply, why?

Answer (score 1):

Gauss's law will apply. According to the Gauss's law, because there is no net charge inside, the divergence of E will be zero (or if you use the integral form, the net flux of E is zero), but that does not mean E=0.

Comment: So how do we differentiate when it applies to flux or when it applies numerically as well, when solving problems? Because if this was a solid sphere, I could apply Gauss' law and get the correct answer. How do I know when it mathematically applies?

Comment: As a rule of thumb, it's best used with situations that have a high degree of symmetry. If your charge distribution were uniform, or there were some pattern to it, Gauss' Law would be perfect, even the flux version.

Comment: Agree. if it is non-uniform without any pattern or symmetry, then probably you you will need to numerically solve, say, the Poisson's equation; then take the gradient to get the field...